# Can someone explain how certain methods get called without being invoked?

Tags: java, inheritance

Here is an example. When the code is ran, the `setup()` and `draw()` methods are called and influence the program. What I don't understand is the fact that there is no method call.

How is this made possible?

```
import processing.core.PApplet;


public class MyDisplay extends PApplet {

    public void setup()
    {
        size(400, 400);
        background(200, 200, 200);

    }

    public void draw()
    {
        fill(255, 255, 0);
        ellipse(200, 200, 390, 390);
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        ellipse(120, 130, 50, 70);
        ellipse(280, 130, 50, 70);

        noFill();
        arc(200, 280, 75, 75, 0, PI);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's explained in the javadoc. Read it: https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html

Comment: I read it but at my level of experience it makes little to no sense. I would appreciate simplification if possible

Comment: A simple trick, when you extends a class, remember that there is more than what you see. A constructor will be called in the super class, it could do "anything". In general, adding an `@Override` annotation to every overriden method (like `setup` and `draw`) help remember that those method are accessible from the super class (because define in the super class or above).

Comment: Ok, but in this case i'm assuming the setup() and draw() methods don't exist in the super class since there is no @Override correct?

Comment: @LinuxOracleUser They do, the `@Override` annotation can be left out and the compiler won't complain about it. However, most IDEs will add the annotation.

Comment: @LinuxOracleUser Also, you **MUST** implement those methods to get a processing app working, so, they exist up there, just as declarations, abstract methods that must be overriden by child Classes.

Comment: The annotation is not mandatory. You can see in the doc that the class have a `draw` and  `setup` method defined. @Shirkam, `PApplet` is not an abstract class so it can't old any abstrat method. The methods are probably empty. (not sure why...)

Comment: @Shirkam That would be nice, but the documentation does not suggest that they actually are abstract?

Comment: @AxelH @Justastudent You both are right. Seeing PApplet code int github shows that `setup` is empty and `draw` changes boolean variable `finished` to `true`, and the program finishes. That's why you must override ***at least*** `draw`.

Answer (score 3):

From the Docs:

"The setup() function is called once when the program starts."

And Draw(): "Called directly after setup() and continuously executes the lines of code contained inside its block until the program is stopped or noLoop() is called."

This is invoked because your class extends PApplet.

You can read more about the functions [here](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/)

Comment: This still doesn't explain how the methods are being invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of what is going on :

Since `MyDisplay` don't have any constructor defined, a *default constructor* will be generated by the compiler. This constructor will be like :

```
public MyDisplay(){
    super();
}
```

It is needed since the superclass need to be generated.

If I believe the documentation of `PApplet` stating that

> The setup() function is called once when the program starts.

And for `draw`

> Called directly after setup()"

The constructor could look like (in a simple version)

```
public class PApplet{
    public PApplet(){
        setup();
        draw();
    }

    public void setup(){}
    public void draw(){}
}
```

Note : those code are not the real one, it could be really far from the truth but this is to show the execution pattern, not the logic behind it !

This means that when a `MyDisplay` instance is build, it will automaticly call the constructor of `PApplet` that will execute those two method. Method that are overriden in `MyDisplay`.

A good advice is to add the annotation `@Override` to both methods to easily notice what method could be execute from above because those are define and overriden.

```
public class MyDisplay extends PApplet {
    @Override
    public void setup()
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void draw()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```